# How do I filter the foreign keys in the django admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAfTw.png) is my admin model `SubQuestion`. What I want to do is to build the models or edit the admin so that it will be filtered according to the foreign keys I chose. How should I proceed?

[image: Admin Model]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use JavaScript for this purpose. Best is probably to use a module such as [django-autocomplete-light](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/) in combination with [select2](https://select2.github.io/).

Then you will be able to [filter results based on the value of other fields in the form](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form).